# БД как реализовать выдачу только определенных записей в зависимости от пользователя

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Суть вопроса в названии.

Делаю курсовую. Схема БД такая:
[image]

Это база данных провайдеров email (чтобы было понятнее, пусть не email, а интернета). Таблица провайдеров (provider), заказчиков
(customer), договоров с заказчиками (contract) и оказанных услуг (service).  Препод хочет, чтобы "когда Вася из Матрикса заходит в базу данных, он не мог даже видеть, не то что изменять записи Феникса". Вроде все логично, только это надо сделать прямо в базе данных. А как?

Если дать права только на процедуры, и делать это в процедуре выборки, то я представляю себе это так: при создании пользователя, где-то запоминать id провайдера, и потом при выборке проверять этот id и выдавать или нет.

```
if(id==current_user.provider_id) then
  do select
else
  nothing
end if;
```

Проблема в том, что это надо сделать через пользователей БД.

Из вариантов только связать login пользователя БД с id провайдера (т.е. добавить столбец в эту колонку). И потом

```
if(provider.db_user=current_user()) then
   do_stuff();
endif;
```

Более элегантные решения есть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, вам подойдёт такой способ ([источник](https://www.sqlmaestro.com/resources/all/row_level_security_mysql/)):

Если кратко:

1. Во все нужные таблицы добавляете колонку с именем юзера, где храните кто может её просматривать.
2. Создаёте представления (View) для нужных таблиц, в `select` добавив условие на совпадение текущего юзера со значением колонки из п1.
3. Выдаёте юзерам права только на представления, не на исходные таблицы.

Так у вас юзеры смогут смотреть и править только свои данные.

Если надо, можно, также, добавить триггер на вставку в исходные таблицы, чтобы при создании новой записи автоматически прописывалось значение в колонку из п1.

Comment: окей, примерно так и сделаю. Т.е. это считается нормальным способом?

Comment: Смешивать сущности уровня таблицы и юзеров уровня сервера БД

Comment: По поводу правильности не скажу. ИМХО выглядит лучше чем ограничение выполнять только заранее заданные процедуры. Но я тут не специалист, просто привел то, что нагуглил и что показалось приемлемым